# Vue.js working with input from a barcode scanner

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events, barcode

I've stumbled upon an interesting case in a web-module, designed for both user- and machine-input (via a barcode scanner). Here is the code from Vue's module:

```html
<input 
    class="form-control"
    v-model="barcode"
    id="barcode-scanner"
    @keyup.enter="parseBarcode"
/>
```

```js
parseBarcode(){
    // validates barcode (string)
    myAPI.getBarcodeId(this.barcode).then(({data}) => {
        if (data.errors) {
            this.showError()
        } else {
            // do some work and focus on input
            this.focusBarcodeInput();
        }
    })
},
```

The scanner can trigger `keyup.enter` at the end, but it inputs the barcode so fast, that the model does not update. Only by adding 10 ms delay after the input (custom setting in the scanner) and then sending `keyup.enter`, everything is working as expected.

The big question is: how can I "slow down" scanner's input instead of tweaking the scanner settings (obviously not convenient for other cases)?

Best regards

Comment: You might want to check [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling it in [this.$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) :

```
parseBarcode () {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    myAPI.getBarcodeId(this.barcode).then(({data}) => {
      if (data.errors) {
        this.showError()
      } else {
        // do some work and focus on input
        this.focusBarcodeInput();
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would give [**nextTick**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) a try

You could use it like this:

```
parseBarcode(){
    // validates barcode (string)
    myAPI.getBarcodeId(this.barcode).then(({data}) => {
        if (data.errors) {
            this.showError()
        } else {
            this.$nextTick(() => {
               this.focusBarcodeInput();
         });
        }
    })
},
```